データベースと接続して、Javaによるログイン遷移画面を作りたい
やりたい事
xmlファイルとJavaを紐付けて、ログイン画面の遷移を行いたい。
現状
xmlファイルを利用してデータベースに接続し、ユーザーページへログインする機能を実装しようとしているのですが、「//データベースに接続」部分において、「コンテキストにバインドされていません。」というエラーを吐いて動作が止まってしまう。
試したこと
・インターネットでの調査
→lookupのパスが原因ではないか？
→dataSource変数にxmlファイルの内容が紐付けられていない？
・eclipseにおいて、デバッグの実施
→全てのdataSource変数でnullを検知（上記の状況なので当たり前ではありますが）
環境
・Eclipse 2018
・Java 8、tomcat 9.0
・PostgreSQL
ソースコード
context.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<Context reloadable="true">
   <Resource
      name="jdbc/Shopping"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
      url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/shopping"
      username="postgresql"
      password="＊＊＊"
　　 />
</Context>


LoginDAO.java
package nl.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class LoginDAO {
    // ログイン判定
    public boolean login(String id, String pass) {
        DataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            Object obj = context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/Shopping");
            dataSource = (DataSource) obj;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
//データベースに接続
        try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ＊ FROM public.user WHERE email LIKE ? AND pass LIKE ?")) {
            pstmt.setString(1, id);
            pstmt.setString(2, pass);
             // try-with-resources 内になくても、PreparedStatement が閉じるとき ResultSet も閉じるので問題なし
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            if (id.equals(rs.getString("email")) && pass.equals(rs.getString("pass"))) {
                // ログイン成功
                return true;
            }
            // ログイン失敗
            return false;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
        // ログイン失敗
        return false;
    }
}

